# Office 2016 Style Ribbon control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using C# and WPF and am after a recommendation for an Office 2016 style ribbon control. It's just me and this is a hobby project so something not too expensive would be ideal (Commercial or FOSS is fine). Ideally, it would look and behave in a similar manner to the ribbons in Office 2016

Comment: Could you provide more information about what, exactly, you're looking for?

Comment: I'm after a WPF Ribbon Control that supports an Office 2016 style. What else do I need to provide? (newbie user here - this is a genuine question).

Comment: It is not a bad question, but it is extremely short, which explains the downvotes (not me)... you could improve it by adding a drawing or screenshot mockup showing exactly what you want to implement. Please also say whether you have a budget, or want gratis, or want open source.

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Studio for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf) includes a [Ribbon control](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/ribbon) with built in support for Office themes.

[image: Office style Ribbon]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks, this is something I'm currently reviewing and it looks promising. However, your Office 2016 Colorful theme doesn't look like Office 2016.

Comment: @making I will check with our development team and get back to you.